# document.querySelector() getting error property properties does not exist on type element

Tags: javascript, angular8

```
const config = document.querySelector('contact-us'); // contact-us is a HTML page
config.properties = configProperties;
```

Comment: document.querySelector is used to get node from the dom tree

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?